# How to handle the back button DrawerNavigation on android with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using the `DrawerLayout` with fragments inside and every fragment navigates to another fragment. I was able to handle the physical back button using :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val callback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_user_validation_to_make_money);
    }
}
```

But every time that I go inside another fragment, the toolbar shows a back button :

[image]

I would like to know how can I handle that back button. Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to handle the back button? Please state your goal clearly.

Answer (score 0):

To navigate using up button, as mentioned in the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity#onSupportNavigateUp()), override `onSupportNavigateUp()` in your activity class

```
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp(drawerLayout)
    }
```

Comment: Can I access from  the fragment ?

Comment: access what? you mean to override in fragment?

Comment: Yeah, like in my app, certain fragments it can only go back to the previous page depending on a certain information, sometimes the Fragment C can't go to B but straight to A, so I need to have that control like I have using the  `onBackPressedDispatcher`.

Comment: IMHO overriding it in mani activity makes total sense coz main activity hosts all the fragments and thereby ensuring correct behavior

Comment: well you can manipulate the back stack as you navigate and the up button just pops up the back stack